# Is the '/category/post-name-date/' permalink structure okay?

Tags: permalinks, codex

> **[Wordpress Codex says](http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks#Structure_Tags):** Make sure to end your structure with either
>   `%post_id%` or `%postname%` (e.g. `/%year%/%monthnum%/%day%/%postname%/`) so
>   that each permalink points to an individual post.

But I would like to set my website's permalink structure (to suite the Google News URL guidelines) like this: `/%category%/%postname%-%year%%monthnum%%day%/`

So, an example URL would look like this:
*http://example.com/internet/hello-world-20120322/*

But this permalink structure appears to be against the quote from WP codex. Do you see any problems with my custom permalink structure? Please advise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a word, No. As long as you have `%postname` somewhere in there you should be fine. Having it at the end, beginning, or middle shouldn't matter. Although the Codex is a great resource it's also edited and written by other WordPress users.

Comment: Small correction -- I think it should be `shouldN'T matter`. Thanks by the way!

Comment: Sorry about that, Fixed :)